# Map value to column where row is equal to column header - pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a new column header in a pandas df that uses certain row values. Using below, for each row in `Group`, I want to map the corresponding value from `Red` of `Blue`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({        
    'Time' : [1,1,1,1,1,1],   
    'Red' : ['1','1','1','4','4','4'],                                   
    'Blue' : ['3','3','3','5','5','5'],                                   
    'Group' : ['Red','Blue','Red','Blue','Red','Blue',],   
    'Output' : ['1','3','1','5','4','5',],                                                               
    })

df['Output'] = np.where(df['Group'] == df['Red'], df['Red'], df['Blue'])
```

intended output:

```
   Time Red Blue Group Output
0     1   1    3   Red      1
1     1   1    3  Blue      3
2     1   1    3   Red      1
3     1   4    5  Blue      5
4     1   4    5   Red      4
5     1   4    5  Blue      5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing:

```
df['Output'] = np.where(df['Group'] == df['Red'], df['Red'], df['Blue'])
#you are making mistake here           ^       ^
```

Do:

```
df['Output'] = np.where(df['Group'] == 'Red', df['Red'], df['Blue'])
```

Output of `df`:

```
    Time    Red     Blue    Group   Output
0   1       1       3       Red     1
1   1       1       3       Blue    3
2   1       1       3       Red     1
3   1       4       5       Blue    5
4   1       4       5       Red     4
5   1       4       5       Blue    5
```